# Linked list in c and MALLOC

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

I'm trying to understand the code below, and I'm having some trouble understanding why there's no seg fault when I run it.  I suppose I need to use malloc to allocate the list at the beginning of the main function?  Can someone explain how the memory for the list is allocated?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct DListElmt_ {

void               *data;
struct DListElmt_  *prev;
struct DListElmt_  *next;

} DListElmt;

typedef struct DList_ {

int                size;

int                (*match)(const void *key1, const void *key2);
void               (*destroy)(void *data);

DListElmt          *head;
DListElmt          *tail;

} DList;

void dlist_init(DList *list, void (*destroy)(void *data));

void dlist_destroy(DList *list);

int dlist_ins_next(DList *list, DListElmt *element, const void *data);

int dlist_ins_prev(DList *list, DListElmt *element, const void *data);

int dlist_remove(DList *list, DListElmt *element, void **data);

#define dlist_size(list) ((list)->size)

#define dlist_head(list) ((list)->head)

#define dlist_tail(list) ((list)->tail)

#define dlist_is_head(element) ((element)->prev == NULL ? 1 : 0)

#define dlist_is_tail(element) ((element)->next == NULL ? 1 : 0)

#define dlist_data(element) ((element)->data)

#define dlist_next(element) ((element)->next)

#define dlist_prev(element) ((element)->prev)

void dlist_init(DList *list, void (*destroy)(void *data)) {
    list->size = 0;
    list->destroy = destroy;
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;

return;

}

void dlist_destroy(DList *list) {

    void    *data;

    while (dlist_size(list) > 0) {

        if (dlist_remove(list, dlist_tail(list), (void **)&data) == 0 && list->destroy != NULL) {

            list->destroy(data);
   }

}

    memset(list, 0, sizeof(DList));

    return;
}

int dlist_ins_next(DList *list, DListElmt *element, const void *data) {

DListElmt          *new_element;

if (element == NULL && dlist_size(list) != 0)
   return -1;

if ((new_element = (DListElmt *)malloc(sizeof(DListElmt))) == NULL)
   return -1;
new_element->data = (void *)data;

if (dlist_size(list) == 0) {
   list->head = new_element;
   list->head->prev = NULL;
   list->head->next = NULL;
   list->tail = new_element;

   }

else {
   new_element->next = element->next;
   new_element->prev = element;

   if (element->next == NULL)
      list->tail = new_element;
   else
      element->next->prev = new_element;

   element->next = new_element;

}
list->size++;

return 0;

}

int dlist_ins_prev(DList *list, DListElmt *element, const void *data) {

DListElmt          *new_element;

if (element == NULL && dlist_size(list) != 0)
   return -1;

if ((new_element = (DListElmt *)malloc(sizeof(DListElmt))) == NULL)
   return -1;

new_element->data = (void *)data;

if (dlist_size(list) == 0) {
   list->head = new_element;
   list->head->prev = NULL;
   list->head->next = NULL;
   list->tail = new_element;

   }


else {
   new_element->next = element; 
   new_element->prev = element->prev;

   if (element->prev == NULL)
      list->head = new_element;
   else
      element->prev->next = new_element;

   element->prev = new_element;

}

list->size++;

return 0;

}

int dlist_remove(DList *list, DListElmt *element, void **data) {

if (element == NULL || dlist_size(list) == 0)
   return -1;

*data = element->data;

if (element == list->head) {

   list->head = element->next;

   if (list->head == NULL)
      list->tail = NULL;
   else
      element->next->prev = NULL;

   }

else {
   element->prev->next = element->next;

   if (element->next == NULL)
      list->tail = element->prev;
   else
      element->next->prev = element->prev;

}

free(element);

list->size--;

return 0;

}

void print_list(const DList *list) {

DListElmt          *element;

int                *data,

fprintf(stdout, "List size is %d\n", dlist_size(list));

i = 0;
element = dlist_head(list);

while (1) {

   data = dlist_data(element);
   fprintf(stdout, "list[%03d]=%03d\n", i, *data);

   i++;

   if (dlist_is_tail(element))
      break;
   else
      element = dlist_next(element);

}

return;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

DList              list;
DListElmt          *element;

int                *data, i;

dlist_init(&list, free);

element = dlist_head(&list);

for (i = 10; i > 0; i--) {

   if ((data = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int))) == NULL)
      return 1;

   *data = i;

   if (dlist_ins_prev(&list, dlist_head(&list), data) != 0)
      return 1;

}

print_list(&list);

element = dlist_head(&list);

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   element = dlist_next(element);

data = dlist_data(element);
fprintf(stdout, "Removing an element after the one containing %03d\n", *data);

if (dlist_remove(&list, element, (void **)&data) != 0)
   return 1;

print_list(&list);

fprintf(stdout, "Inserting 011 at the tail of the list\n");

*data = 11;
if (dlist_ins_next(&list, dlist_tail(&list), data) != 0)
   return 1;

print_list(&list);

fprintf(stdout, "Removing an element at the tail of the list\n");

element = dlist_tail(&list);
if (dlist_remove(&list, element, (void **)&data) != 0)
   return 1;

print_list(&list);

fprintf(stdout, "Inserting 012 just before the tail of the list\n");

*data = 12;
if (dlist_ins_prev(&list, dlist_tail(&list), data) != 0)
   return 1;

print_list(&list);

fprintf(stdout, "Iterating and removing the fourth element\n");

element = dlist_head(&list);
element = dlist_next(element);
element = dlist_prev(element);
element = dlist_next(element);
element = dlist_prev(element);
element = dlist_next(element);
element = dlist_next(element);
element = dlist_next(element);

if (dlist_remove(&list, element, (void **)&data) != 0)
   return 1;

print_list(&list);

fprintf(stdout, "Inserting 013 before the first element\n");

*data = 13;
if (dlist_ins_prev(&list, dlist_head(&list), data) != 0)
   return 1;

print_list(&list);

fprintf(stdout, "Removing an element at the head of the list\n");

if (dlist_remove(&list, dlist_head(&list), (void **)&data) != 0)
   return 1;

print_list(&list);

fprintf(stdout, "Inserting 014 just after the head of the list\n");
*data = 14;

if (dlist_ins_next(&list, dlist_head(&list), data) != 0)
   return 1;

print_list(&list);

fprintf(stdout, "Inserting 015 two elements after the head of the list\n");

if ((data = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int))) == NULL)
   return 1;

*data = 15;
element = dlist_head(&list);
element = dlist_next(element);

if (dlist_ins_next(&list, element, data) != 0)
   return 1;

print_list(&list);

i = dlist_is_head(dlist_head(&list));
fprintf(stdout, "Testing dlist_is_head...Value=%d (1=OK)\n", i);
i = dlist_is_head(dlist_tail(&list));
fprintf(stdout, "Testing dlist_is_head...Value=%d (0=OK)\n", i);
i = dlist_is_tail(dlist_tail(&list));
fprintf(stdout, "Testing dlist_is_tail...Value=%d (1=OK)\n", i);
i = dlist_is_tail(dlist_head(&list));
fprintf(stdout, "Testing dlist_is_tail...Value=%d (0=OK)\n", i);

fprintf(stdout, "Destroying the list\n");
dlist_destroy(&list);

return 0;

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please do not repost a question that was closed, even if the close was invalid -- that is very bad behavior here.

Comment: You want us to read _your_ 300+ lines of unformatted code and explain to you why it doesn't crash?  Sorry but I pass.

Comment: @Jeff M : why the agressivity? you can pass without commenting my question it's a better behavior. Thanks

Comment: You obviously don't know anything about C -- please learn a little first, and actually make an effort on your own.

Comment: @Gallois: I'm sorry you took that as being aggressive.  But really, this is not a "question" for stack overflow.  I would have _loved_ to help you _if_ what you had was readable and you didn't treat it as "here's my code, why does it do this?"  It is impossible to read without fixing it myself first.  If it was just a code snippet and you discussed what you thought about it, then maybe it would be more tolerable.  Normally I might try and help you get your question in line but this is just excessive and is not really worth the effort.  If _you_ put some effort at it, then I might do the same.

Comment: @Jeff Two people gave the answer so it obviously isn't impossible. It took me about ten seconds, because I actually bothered to read what the OP wrote: "I suppose I need to use malloc to allocate the list at the beginning of the main function?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linked list in c and memory allocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139939/linked-list-in-c-and-memory-allocation)

Comment: @Jim: That was an exaggeration.  Of course it's not impossible.  I saw the answer too when I was considering editing the question to be readable.  _But_ aside from that statement, that doesn't show me that he made any effort in asking a _good_ question.  There was 0 improvement from his last question.  Rather than trying to make the question better, I opted to stop all my efforts and leave my comment on why.  I'm definitely not alone on this position.

Comment: @Jeff it wasn't even close to true. I won't defend the quality of the OP's question -- that's a different issue.

Comment: @Cody Of course it's a duplicate, but that one was wrongly closed.

Comment: @Jim: There's a "reopen" button for all of those who think so. The fact that a question was "wrongly closed" doesn't justify posting *exactly the same thing* a few minutes later. This is a duplicate, in every definition of the word.

Comment: @Cody Not at my reputation level there isn't. And who said it is justified? I wrote above "that is very bad behavior here". But the OP is a newbie who doesn't know better; those who closed that should. (FAQ: be nice.)

Comment: @Jim: Sorry, I didn't read all of the comments. I only read the question. There's very little debate that can be had over whether or not this is a duplicate. Also, sorry that there isn't a "reopen" link at your reputation level. I'm not sure what you want me to do about that. The question didn't *improve* any since it was first posted, so this is clearly an *exact* duplicate, just what the close reason says. Beyond that, there is absolutely *nothing* not nice about closing a question. If you're offended by that, you need to get out more.

Comment: @Cody "There's very little debate that can be had over whether or not this is a duplicate" -- and so I said "Of course it's a duplicate". "If you're offended by that, you need to get out more" -- You seem to be intent on being rude. Goodbye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list (which is the list header) is allocated on the stack. Its elements are malloced.

Comment: can you explain better please.

Comment: @Gallois I have no idea what about that answer you don't understand. If you know nothing at all about C -- and that's all that I can imagine -- then you shouldn't be asking questions about C programs.

Comment: There are quite a few sociopaths at SO but the worst are those who do drive-by downvotes of years old **accepted answers**.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
DList              list;
```

allocates the list on the stack. Then in dlist_ins_prev space is allocated on the heap for each element.

Comment: When i use `DList *list`instead do i need to do some allocation : `list = (DList *) malloc (sizeof (DList))`?